# If an I2C connection is lost for a short period of time will it work if the connection is live again?

Tags: esp8266, i2c

I'm using an ESP8266 with the Arduino library to read from a sensor([MPU9250](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/RM-MPU-9250A-00-v1.6.pdf) specifically). The readings are done via I2C but I'm using a library that abstracts these methods.

The wires are not soldered together so temporary disconnections are possible and after these disconnects the sensor readings freeze. I'm new to the world of I2C so my questions are:

- Do I have to re-init the connection after it disconnects or is there a way to continue on re-connection immediately?
- Is there a way to prevent this to happen (for example to stop reading when there's no connection) or should I just solder together the pins?

Answer (score 1):

When an I2C master starts a transmission or a request from a slave, it sends the slaves address and then check for an acknowledgement (ACK) from the slave (SDA LOW, when the clock has a HIGH pulse). When no slave is connected, or there is no slave with this address, then there isn't any circuit to pull SDA to LOW on the clock pulse, that is generated by the master. This is interpreted as No acknowledgement (NACK) and the transmission/request fails and should exit. So a disconnection between the transmission should not freeze your code (though I don't know what your library is doing exactly).

A quick google search gives me, that the esp8266 does not have hardware I2C, so your library does a pure software I2C. There are many pitfalls, which can block the I2C bus (especially, if one the lines is hold LOW by one of the involving circuits). Your library may or may not implement the correct I2C protocoll.

So to clearly answer your questions:

1. You don't have to reinit connection. Your master transmission fails, if there is no slave, and should give you an error as return value. But be sure, that there isn't happening anything on the SDA or SCL lines, when it starts up again after reconnection. Master or slave can interpret voltage spikes as signal.
2. If the library is implemented correctly, it will exit, when there is no ACK from the slave.

Look into the documentation of your library how it handles these events. And check the state of SDA and SCL, when a block occures. You can refer to [this site](http://www.i2c-bus.org/i2c-primer/analysing-obscure-problems/blocked-bus/) for further information about I2C. It also gives some advice if your bus is blocked.